# MongoDB: single find request to return data from different documents with different fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this collection:

```
{
    "name": "Leonardo",
    "height": "180",
    "weapon": "sword",
    "favorite_pizza": "Hawai"
},
{
    "name": "Donatello",
    "height": "181",
    "weapon": "stick",
    "favorite_pizza": "Pepperoni"
},
{
    "name": "Michelangelo",
    "height": "182",
    "weapon": "nunchucks",
    "favorite_pizza": "Bacon"
},
{
    "name": "Raphael",
    "height": "183",
    "weapon": "sai",
    "favorite_pizza": "Margherita"
}
```

With using one query I want this result (ordered by height):

```
{
    "name": "Leonardo",
    "height": "180",
    "weapon": "sword",
    "favorite_pizza": "Hawai"
},
{
    "name": "Donatello",
},
{
    "name": "Michelangelo",
},
{
    "name": "Raphael",
}
```

So the query needs to first get the document which has smallest height field and then get all contents of that document, then it needs to get all other documents and return only name field of those documents, while ordering those documents by height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your height to numeric for correct sorting and you can try below aggregation in 3.4 pipeline.

The query `$sorts` the document by "height" ascending followed by `$group` to create two fields, "first" field which has the smallest height record (`$$ROOT` to access the whole document) and "allnames" to record all names.

`$project` with `$slice` + `$concatArrays` to replace the "allnames" array first element with the smallest height document and get the updated array.

`$unwind` with `$replaceRoot` to promote all the docs to top level.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
{"$sort":{
  "height":1
}},
{"$group":{
  "_id":null,
  "first":{"$first":"$$ROOT"},
  "allnames":{"$push":{"name":"$name"}}
}},
{"$project":{
  "data":{"$concatArrays":[["$first"],{"$slice":["$allnames",1,{"$size":"$allnames"}] } ]}
}},
{"$unwind":"$data"},
{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$data"}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness reasons...

@Veeram's answer is probably the better choice (I have a feeling it should be faster and easier to understand) but you can achieve the same result using a slightly simpler `$group` stage followed by slightly more complex `$project` stage using `$reduce`:

```
collection.aggregate([{
    $sort: {
        "height": 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id":null,
        "allnames": {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "data": {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$allnames",
                initialValue: null,
                in: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: [ "$$value", null ] // if it's the first time we come here
                    },
                    [ "$$this" ], // we include the entire document
                    {
                        $concatArrays: [ // else we concat
                            "$$value",   // the already concatenated values
                            [ { "name": "$$this.name" } ] // with the "name" of the currently looked at document
                        ]
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$data"
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        "newRoot": "$data"
    }
}])
```

Alternatively - as pointed out by @Veeram in the comment below - , it's possible to write the $reduce in this way:

```
$project: {
    "data": {
        $reduce: {
            input: { "$slice": [ "$allnames", 1, { $size: "$allnames" } ] }, // process everything in the "allnames" array except for the first item
            initialValue: { "$slice": [ "$allnames", 1 ] }, // start with the first item
            in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ { "name": "$$this.name" } ] ]} // and keep appending the "name" field of all other items only
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify reduce to `{
     $reduce: {
         input:{"$slice":["$allnames",1,{"$size":"$allnames"}] },
         initialValue: {"$slice":["$allnames",1]},
         in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", [ { "name": "$$this.name" } ] ]}
     }
   }`